# Why are my hashes printed as strings?

Tags: ruby

It's pretty wierd, but I do not know what to configure or where to configure. I am trying to print a simple hash value as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

names = Hash.new
names[1] = "Jane"
names[2] = "Thomas"

puts names
```

I expect the output to be

```
{1=>"Jane", 2=>"Thomas"}
```

while I get

```
1Jane2Thomas
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems you are using Ruby 1.8. In Ruby 1.9 you *do* get the output you expect. Oldergod's answer solves your problem in 1.8.

Comment: Voila, my version of ruby is 1.8.7. Yes, indeed the answer works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use inspect.

```
puts names.inspect
#=> {1=>"Jane", 2=>"Thomas"}
```

Answer (score 3):

The *puts* method calls **to_s** on its argument(s) and prints the result. The *p* method however calls **inspect** on its argument(s) and prints the result:

```
{1=>"Jane", 2=>"Thomas"}.to_s
#=> '1Jane2Thomas'

{1=>"Jane", 2=>"Thomas"}.inspect
#=> '{1=>"Jane", 2=>"Thomas"}'
```

So, to have a nice Hash printout, either use

```
puts {1=>"Jane", 2=>"Thomas"}.inspect
```

or

```
p {1=>"Jane", 2=>"Thomas"}
```